# JQuery.Validate only validates first field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I've been struggling all day with a JQuery validate issue. Where it only validates the first field.

I've managed to reproduce it here:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#go').click(function() {
    
    console.log('go clicked');
    
    if ($('#detailsForm').valid()) {
      alert('if you see this then the form is valid.');
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@1.10.0" data-semver="1.10.0" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="jquery-validate@1.10.0" data-semver="1.10.0" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script data-require="jquery-validate@1.10.0" data-semver="1.10.0" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.0/additional-methods.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>This doesn't work :(</h1>
    
     <form id="detailsForm">

        <div class="row guttered-bottom">

            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">


                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                        <br />
                        First Name<div style="color:#E320C9">*</div>
                        <div class="input-container">
                            <input id="ReserveFirstName" type="text" class="input-large input-wide" placeholder="Enter your first name" required="true" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

           <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                        <br />
                        Last Name<div style="color:#E320C9">*</div>
                        <div class="input-container">
                            <input id="ReserveLastName" type="text" class="input-large input-wide" placeholder="Enter your last name" required="true" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

         
        </div>


    </form>
    
    <br>
    
    <button id="go">CLICK ME! </button>
  </body>

</html>
```

Steps to reproduce: click the button and observe that the validation message comes up for the first field (first name). Enter a first name and click the button again. Notice that the form seems to validate even though both fields are required.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think this is quite a duplicate. It's similar yes but not a duplicate question.

Comment: For this plugin to work, the form input elements need to have unique `name` attributes.  If they are not unique or they are missing, the symptom is exactly what you describe.  Whether validation is triggered manually by a button or programmatically by the `.valid()` method is irrelevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery Validate needs each input to have a `name` attribute.  Without this, it can't properly create the input objects it uses to store validation results.

Just add a unique name to each input and you should be good:

```
<input name="ReserveFirstName" id="ReserveFirstName" type="text" class="input-large input-wide" placeholder="Enter your first name" required="true" />

<input name="ReserveLastName" id="ReserveLastName" type="text" class="input-large input-wide" placeholder="Enter your last name" required="true" />
```

Comment: Pat I wish I'd asked this earlier rather than struggling! thank you so much! I can't accept this answer for another 10 minutes.

Comment: Similarly a form won't submit inputs with no name which is also why they get ignored for validation

Comment: @charlietfl good to know but shouldn't affect me in this case. Thanks though I upvoted you for that.

Comment: Np @PrimeByDesign - the same thing got me years ago.

Comment: Validate also ignores fields that are disabled.  Not applicable to your issue, but just an fyi.

Comment: @Taplar actually that does affect me in my actual implementation... it works in my favor I have a select with options. I use a disabled option "please select" to act as a placeholder.

Comment: Well there ya go, :)

Comment: Thank you all so much for your quick answers! You're awesome!

Comment: We have been struggling to understand what is missing. Thanks